# Contact Form Not Working or Displaying Confirmation / Failed Message

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, contact-us, contact-form

I have a contact form on my Contact Us page as follows;

```
{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```

The form displays correctly but when I click 'Submit' the page simply refreshes, clears the form, and no confirmation/failed message displays.  I also don't receive any email.

In my `System > Configuration > Contacts` I have `Enable Contact Us` set to `Enabled` and a correct email address in `Send Emails To`.

For the record, I'm using Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's happening because the action attribute of form gets set by the controller file of the module, which is not being called as you are placing it on a custom page. You'll need to add that action to the form for proper submit behavior of contact form.
For a quick fix, if you have your form.phtml file in theme folder, you can change the form action in it as :

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Comment: Hello @Prateek  Thank you for your response - it worked :) The form now submits successfully and I receive an email with the contents.  One last thing.. I notice the form redirects to 'contacts/index' upon submission.  Is it possible to redirect to a custom page, such as a 'thank you' page or something?  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's completely possible. You'll have to rewrite the controller. You can look around for it,  it's pretty easy.

Comment: This replacement work for the Pagayo pt004 electronic theme too.

Comment: hi, i am getting 404 page error on this url : /contacts/index/post. can you help?

Comment: @Gaurav, it's very much likely due to some incorrect rewrite of core module. Try starting with the basic troubleshooting of Magento application.