# Magento 1.9 not sending contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, contact-form

My magento is not sending contact form for my e-mail, the other sales e-mails is working/sending normally, i checked the crons and system > Configuration > Store email adresses, checked Contacts too,

when i write the contact form and press button "send", it returns success for form.

the url comes to mydomain.com/contacts/index/

i'm using http in a shared host,
Php version 7.0

i Try to follow this post [Contact Form Not Working or Displaying Confirmation / Failed Message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76775/contact-form-not-working-or-displaying-confirmation-failed-message?answertab=oldest#tab-top)    but it does not work too.

Comment: Can you check spam folder of your inbox? Also check the log files for any errors.

Comment: Hi i checked my spam, but it is empty, and in /var there is no log referent this error.

Comment: Is other mails are sending properly like registration and orders etc.

Comment: registration, reset password is sending email normally, but order, and another sales e-mails is not working too.